# How do you create a timespan from milliseconds in powershell?

Tags: powershell

New-Timespan takes no "MilliSeconds" parameter, how do you create a TimeSpan from milliseconds?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of [PowerShell v7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-73) there is a [`-Milliseconds` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan#-milliseconds) of `New-TimeSpan`...

```
PS> New-TimeSpan -Milliseconds 10

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 10
Ticks             : 100000
TotalDays         : 1.15740740740741E-07
TotalHours        : 2.77777777777778E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0.000166666666666667
TotalSeconds      : 0.01
TotalMilliseconds : 10
```

Otherwise, use the [`FromMilliseconds` static method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.frommilliseconds) of the [`TimeSpan` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan)...

```
PS> [TimeSpan]::FromMilliseconds(10)


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 10
Ticks             : 100000
TotalDays         : 1.15740740740741E-07
TotalHours        : 2.77777777777778E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0.000166666666666667
TotalSeconds      : 0.01
TotalMilliseconds : 10
```

A `TimeSpan` ultimately represents its duration as a number of [`Ticks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticks), so if you prefer to think of it that way you can multiply the number of milliseconds by the [`TicksPerMillisecond` constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tickspermillisecond) and pass that to [the constructor that accepts the number of ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int64_) (there is no `FromTicks()` method)...

```
PS> New-Object -TypeName 'TimeSpan' -ArgumentList (10 * [TimeSpan]::TicksPerMillisecond)

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 10
Ticks             : 100000
TotalDays         : 1.15740740740741E-07
TotalHours        : 2.77777777777778E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0.000166666666666667
TotalSeconds      : 0.01
TotalMilliseconds : 10


PS> [TimeSpan]::new(10 * [TimeSpan]::TicksPerMillisecond)

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 10
Ticks             : 100000
TotalDays         : 1.15740740740741E-07
TotalHours        : 2.77777777777778E-06
TotalMinutes      : 0.000166666666666667
TotalSeconds      : 0.01
TotalMilliseconds : 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Positive: **[timespan]'0:0:0.001'** or **[timespan]'00:00:00:00.001'**

Negative: **[timespan]'-0:0:0.001'** or **[timespan]'-00:00:00:00.001'**

Specifying 4 or 5 [int32] numbers get interpreted as (optionally days,) hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

For a more complete answer see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-understanding-timespan-objects/ and scroll down to TimeSpan constructors.

Each time unit specified must stay within its usual limits (0-23 for hours, 0-59 for minutes and seconds, 0-999 for milliseconds). The days range (if specified) is 0-10675199.

The highest possible [timespan] value appears to be **[timespan]'10675199:2:48:5.477'** (verified on PowerShell 5.1 and pwsh 7.1.1).

Comment: _So_ close.  `[TimeSpan]::MaxValue.ToString()` yields `10675199.02:48:05.4775807`, so you're about a half millisecond (or 5,807 [ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticks)) off on the maximum `TimeSpan` value; you can see this with `[TimeSpan]::MaxValue - [TimeSpan] '10675199:2:48:5.477'`.

Answer (score 0):

10,000 ticks (integer, not float or string) is 1 millisecond:

```
[timespan]10000


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 1
Ticks             : 10000
TotalDays         : 1.15740740740741E-08
TotalHours        : 2.77777777777778E-07
TotalMinutes      : 1.66666666666667E-05
TotalSeconds      : 0.001
TotalMilliseconds : 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$Start_DateTime = Get-Date -format HH:mm:ss.fff
...... other commnads
$Finish_DateTime = Get-Date -format HH:mm:ss.fff
$TimeDiff = New-TimeSpan $Start_DateTime $Finish_DateTime 
IF ($TimeDiff.Seconds -lt 0) 
{ $Hrs = ($TimeDiff.Hours) + 23
  $Mins = ($TimeDiff.Minutes) + 59
  $Secs = ($TimeDiff.Seconds) + 59 
  $Milliseconds = ($TimeDiff.Milliseconds) + 59 
}
ELSE 
{ $Hrs = $TimeDiff.Hours
  $Mins = $TimeDiff.Minutes
  $Secs = $TimeDiff.Seconds 
  $Milliseconds = $TimeDiff.Milliseconds
}
```